# Picking useful values out of text messages with Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

Imagine somebody is sending you a mail like this every day:

**Example 1:**

> "My fuel consumption yesterday was XXX liters, My distance driven is
>   YYY kilometers/miles, My average speed yesterday ZZZ kilometers/miles
>   per hour "

**Example 2:**

> "The engine used XXX liters of fuel yesterday, The car drove YYY
>   kilometers yesterday (+3 kilometers after 12 o'clock, but this was
>   technically today), The car's mean speed yesterday is ZZZ kilometers
>   per hour"

There can be more values into the mail, up to 5 values (in this example there are 3).

The task is to get the `XXX,YYY and ZZZ` (and more when there are more) values out of the mail. Of course, the mail is manually typed, so each mail is of a different kind.

The question is, how to do this?
Every (serious) idea is welcome, I will give my thoughts of it below:

I thought a **Keras** (or any other) Neural Network might do the job. I tried to let each mail be represented by a numpy vector using `keras.preprocessing.text.one_hot()` and train a Neural Network on it with the following structure:

> 1. EmbeddingLayer
> 2. 1DConvLayer with Relu activation
> 3. MaxpoolLayer
> 4. DropoutLayer
> 5. FlattenLayer
> 6. DenseLayer with Relu activation
> 7. DropoutLayer
> 8. Dense Layer with Linear activation

For the examples above, there would be 3 output neurons where each neuron should predict a value, for example the first output neuron should output XXX, second neuron YYY, and so on.

Using the **Adam optimizer** and the MSE as loss, this does a bad job. MSE seems to converge to a rather large value and the predictions are way off.

Should I use another structure? Which structure has the best change of succeeding?

Should I use a totally different output? for example, the neural network outputs: "the sixth word is the fuel consumption".

Should I use a radically different approach without a Neural network at all? What would work then?

An example of a message with the Neural network's output. The mail message:

```
 - Cargo quantity, B/L mt: 0 
 - ME Fuel consumption mt: 8,9 
 - Total fuel consumption mt: 15
 - Draught m: 6,65
 - Date: 2018-07-04 07:00
 - Timezone: 2018-07-04 07:00 W. Europe Standard Time 
 - ROB MGO: 510,3
 - Distance, 127
```

**Neural network Output:**

> - Date: 2018-09-12T15:02:28
> - Timezone: 545.405
> - ROB MGO: -1876.67
> - Cargo: 23714.6
> - Draught: 0.394458
> - Cargo offload: 9.97439e+06
> - Cargo load: 9.87113e+06

**Desired output:**

> - Date: 2018-04-07T07:00:00
> - Timezone: +1
> - ROB MGO: 510.3
> - Cargo: 0
> - Draught: 6.65
> - Cargo offload: 99999999
> - Cargo load: 99999999

The timezone represents the difference towards UTC, in this case +1, Cargo offload and Cargo load are not present in the mail, so they should output 99999999 which means "not present". Dates are first converted to timestamps, so the neural network outputs a timestamp.

Comment: Just a thought...The mails can be processed and stored as the text...then make a keyword list for all your entities like liters, kilometer/miles etc. etc. Then write a regex to extract the numbers.

Comment: I think a regex doesn't work since the emails can be very different. Like I said, they are manually typed by different persons every day. Do you still think a regex will work? If you think so, can you give me a good example? Thank you!

Comment: As I said, for your corpus of emails you can make a list how 1 particular entity is written by users. If it is lets say 5-10 ways, it can be handled. if it is like 100 ways for 1 entity, then also it can handle but it will not be efficient. So, for example XXX liters can be written as liters, lts, litters etc. etc. . Store this list in excel and pass it to regex. In future, if you have to add a word it will easy to modify an excel

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I would love to see that!

Comment: Please see the answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in following steps:

1. Make an excel file with 2 columns named "**Name**" and **Pattern**". Where "Name" is the capturing group (**Draught/Cargo offload**) and the "pattern" is required regex to achieve to capture it.
2. Read this excel in python with below command:

> ```
> import pandas as pd
> df = pd.read_excel('\\Regex.xlsx', sheet_name=0)
> ```

3. Pass this `df` to below functions which will help you to parse excel of regex(es) and then parse it:

> ```
> def parse_patterns_regex(df):
>     pattern = df['pattern'].tolist()
>     pattern_name = df['name'].tolist()
>     pattern_dict = dict(zip(pattern_name, pattern))
>     return pattern_dict
> ```

4. Pass the `pattern dict` and `text`(your emails) to below functions to get the desired output

> ```
> def find_patterns_regex(text, pattern_dict,sep = ' ;; '):
>         NLU_Dict=collections.defaultdict()
>         for pn, p in pattern_dict.items():
>             val = sep.join([sep.join(filter(lambda x: len(str(x).strip()) >0,map(str, v))) for v in re.findall(p, text,re.I)])
>             NLU_Dict[pn] = val
>         return NLU_Dict
> ```

`NLU_Dict` will be a dictionary of the capturing group and the corresponding values. The values which are not in the mail will be simply blank. You can just write a simple logic to convert `blank to 999999` etc.

5. **Sample regex to be written in excel**:

> ```
> Capturing Group: Fuel Consumption ## This is "name" column of the above excel
> Regex:(\d+)\s?(?i)liters?|(\d+)\s?(?i)litters? ##This is "pattern" column of the above excel
> ```

See the below link to see the regex work:
https://regex101.com/r/IppEq0/1

6. Now you need to write more regex for your capturing group and put in the excel